# add show/hide hidden files icon in OSX finder window

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I can follow this script to show or hide hidden files on a mac, it works. Is there a way to add an icon to the finder window that on click toggles this functionality?

http://www.techiecorner.com/153/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-finder-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- **Make a double-clickable AppleScript file** with above commands and
  drag the icon into your sidebar or top window bar. [This article](http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/how_to_toggle_invisible_files_in_osx) might help.
- Use the **[Secrets](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/) PrefPane** to un/set *Finder* → *Show hidden files*
- Use the [**hiddenfiles**](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) Dashboard Widget

Comment: That article was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.